# GLSL odd even merge sort

Tags: sorting, glsl, gpu, mergesort, fragment-shader

I'm trying to understand [the odd-ever merge sort example](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter46.html) on the gpugems site but I'm having trouble figuring out some of what they are passing into the uniforms. Here's the shader in it's entirety.

```
uniform vec3 Param1;
uniform vec3 Param2;
uniform sampler2D Data;

#define OwnPos gl_TexCoord[0]

// contents of the uniform data fields
#define TwoStage Param1.x
#define Pass_mod_Stage Param1.y
#define TwoStage_PmS_1 Param1.z
#define Width Param2.x
#define Height Param2.y
#define Pass Param2.z

void main(void){
// get self
vec4 self = texture2D(Data, OwnPos.xy);

float i = floor(OwnPos.x * Width) + floor(OwnPos.y * Height) * Width;

// my position within the range to merge
float j = floor(mod(i, TwoStage));

float compare;

if ( (j < Pass_mod_Stage) || (j > TwoStage_PmS_1) )
  // must copy -> compare with self
  compare = 0.0;
else
  // must sort
  if ( mod((j + Pass_mod_Stage) / Pass, 2.0) < 1.0)
    // we are on the left side -> compare with partner on the right
    compare = 1.0;
  else
    // we are on the right side -> compare with partner on the left
    compare = -1.0;

// get the partner
float adr = i + compare * Pass;

vec4 partner = texture2D(Data, vec2(floor(mod(adr, Width)) / Width, floor(adr / Width) / Height));

// on the left it's a < operation; on the right it's a >= operation
gl_FragColor = (self.x * compare < partner.x * compare) ? self : partner;
}
```

The part that's tripping me up is figuring out what they are assigning to Param1 and Param2.z.

Param2.x and Param2.y are just width and height of the image. Is the pass variable just an incrementing number each time through the loop?

Param1.x, Param1.y, and Param1.z have me completely stumped. Is there supposed to be something going on in the CPU side of this program that they are not including here?

Any help or clarity would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for this example is available [here](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/GPU_Gems_2/CD/Content/46.zip).
The line 298 of the `main.cpp` file is the one that you need:

```
glUniform3fARB(oddevenMergeSort.getUniformLocation("Param1"),
    float(pstage+pstage),
    float(ppass%pstage),
    float((pstage+pstage)-(ppass%pstage)-1)
);
glUniform3fARB(oddevenMergeSort.getUniformLocation("Param2"),
    float(width),
    float(height),
    float(ppass)
);
```

With `int ppass = 1<<pass;` and `int pstage = 1<<stage;`